Этот ответ утвердительный?
"данный текст действительно может быть воспринят как оскорбительный для русской нации."
Этот ответ при анализе текста утвердительный?

Данный текст действительно может быть воспринят как оскорбительный для русской нации.

Да, это утвердительный вывод. Необособленное наречие "действительно" имеет значение «на самом деле, подлинно».  Это именно наречие, что видно по позиции слова: вводное слово чаще стоит в начале предложения.

Изменим позицию слова "действительно" и будем считать его вводным: Действительно, данный текст может быть воспринят как оскорбительный для русской нации.


Теперь оно может быть: (1) выводом о том, что сказанное ранее верно, или (2) предпосылкой к последующему рассуждению.

И вот во втором случае вывод может быть отрицательным: можно предположить, но это не так.

Справочник по пунктуации

А как же быть с может быть? "На самом деле может быть" как-то не убеждает.

Отрицательный вывод можно записать так: Данный текст, действительно, может быть воспринят как оскорбительный для русской нации, но на самом деле ничего оскорбительного там нет. Утвердительный вывод: Данный текст, действительно, может быть воспринят как оскорбительный для русской нации ( с обособлением и без обособления).

Но у вас в обоих случаях с обособлением.


В заданном предложении необособленное наречие, там только утверждение. 2, Если обособить вводное слово, то это предпосылка для рассуждения (возможны два вывода). 3. О позиции "действительно".   Практически вводное слово обычно стоит в начале предложения, хотя запрета на другую позицию нет.


Нет, вы не поняли: у вас и утвердительный вывод и отрицательный — обособленный. Но вы говорите, что один вариант обособлен, а другой нет.
